# How could I access my server when ubuntu server connected to a VPN?

Tags: vpn, pptp

My server has to connect to a VPN by using PPTP.

I purchased a VPS, and it comes with VNC. In order to access to a foreign website I used the Ubuntu GUI to created a VPN connection to a foreign server.

I am wondering how could I access my server via FTP then?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! What do you mean by "access"? FTP is a file transfer protocol, not a remote shell (like SSH).

Comment: I want to download some files from the server, but my server connected to a VPN, I am not able to connect my server by using my ftp software.

Comment: I still don't get why the VPN "has to" connect to a VPN, especially why it has to route **all** traffic to the VPN and not only some traffic. Could you update your question with an explanation of the network topology? A diagram with the involved nodes might be desirable.

Comment: I am really new to Linux, just couple weeks. In order to access to a foreign website I used ubuntu GUI to created a VPN connection to a foreign server. That's all I am doing. I don't know how to route traffic at all. Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Wait, your server has a GUI? And moreover: how do you interact with such a GUI? It means you are already connecting to the server. This is relevant information, please add it to your question.

Comment: I purchased a VPS, and it comes with VNC. I didn't know how to manage it with command-line, so I tried to use it with GUI.

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

> I used the Ubuntu GUI to created a VPN connection to a foreign server

This is the wrong way of doing it. A VPS should be managed through SSH and configured properly. Network Manager is not suitable for this because it does not allow for *split tunneling.* It's an all or nothing approach.

## How to fix the VPN

> How could I access my server via FTP then?

Disable the VPN in Network Manager. Instead, set up a VPN by routing only traffic to the website and its subdomains. I do it on my VPS as well.

- Pick up the OpenVPN configuration file provided by your provider and copy its contents to `/etc/openvpn/openvpn.conf`
- Add this directive to the bottom of the file:

  ```
  # No automatic routes
  route-noexec
  ```
- Save the file and issue `sudo service openvpn restart`

This will make sure that the VPN is picked up by Systemd and its service located at:

```
/lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service
```

Now you should see the `tun0` interface with `ifconfig`. The VPN is active but **no traffic** is going through it for now. The last step is making sure you add routes to the domains you need.

- Found the IP of the website with `dig`:

  ```
  dig +short example.com
  ```
- Add a route (there are also other approaches, but this one is simple for a few hosts):

  ```
  ip route add [insert IP here] dev ppp0
  ```
- Repeat these steps for the `www.` subdomain and other domains you may need to route through the VPN

The routes should be updated once in a while, because the website might change IP address. You can write a Bash script and run it periodically using `cron` to avoid doing it manually.

## Alternative approach

If you are trying to access a geo-restricted video website, e.g. Hulu, you might consider using a SmartDNS service. That will take care of split tunneling for you. You will just need to update the DNS settings on the server.

However, this only works if the SmartDNS provider of your choice supports that particular website.

## Connect to the server

You can now connect to your server using its IP address.